# Inlining the UnrealEngine UE_LOG macro with C++

Tags: c++, macros, inline, unreal-engine4

I'm new to Unreal Engine, and I'm trying to declare an `inline` function as following:

```
void inline Print(const char* s) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), s);
}
```

In order to avoid the call to `UE_LOG` with `LogTemp` and `Warning` every time.

When calling for example `Print("Hello")`, the output is `LogTemp:Warning: 效汬o`.

My guess is something related to the ASCII encoding, but I'm really not sure.

I also tried to use `reinterpret_cast` as following:

```
void inline Print(const char* s) {
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), reinterpret_cast<const TCHAR *>(s));
}
```

But ended up with same results.

I'd like to know the right way of doing it (I didn't want to use MACRO over inline func), and if there's a simple explanation to what's the reason for the gibberish output, it will also be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't give `const char*` to `UE_LOG`, it requires `const TCHAR*`, also it can't be `reinterpret_cast`ed that way, it needs a conversion, but just let `FString` handles the dirty work for you. I think you can choose one of the following:

1.

```
inline void Print(const FString& s)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *s);
}
```

2.

```
inline void Print(const char* s)
{
    FString str(s);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *str);
}
```