# Is there a way to directly translate C's "%02x" format to C++?

Tags: c++, c, formatting, format, stringstream

I am following a tutorial in which they use `BIO_printf(bio_out,"%02x",bs->data[i] );` in order to get the characters of a serial number stored in `bs->data` (which is an array of unsigned char) and they use `"%02x"` to specify the format of the char. I am using c++ and I want to add each of these chars to a `stringstream` but I can't find a way to translate the format and instead of a serial number I get `ጄ냾�㮚㭖嵺ﭔ촋ᙰ`.

I have tried using

```
std::stringstream serial("Serial: ");
for (int i = 0; i < bs->length; i++) 
{
    serial << std::setw(2) << std::hex << bs->data[i] << std::endl;
}
```

but I still don't get a valid string, and

```
char* buffer = const_cast<char*>(serial.str().c_str());
sprintf(buffer, "%02x", bs->data[i]);
```

doesn't seem to work either (don't mind the const cast, I know it is bad practice)

Comment: Please show us the stream-based code that didn't work.  I think I know what might be wrong, but I can't comment on code I can't see.

Comment: Does htis answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c

Comment: @PaulSanders I hope the edited version explains better my aproach

Comment: Where in your for loop do you actually access `bs->data[i]`?

Comment: @Botje I'm sorry, I forgot to add it in the edit

Comment: Where do you **use** serial? Since you say it prints something with weird characters.

Comment: I am using it just to know if the output of the reading is correct. So I am logging it to the console later in the code @Botje

Comment: *how* are you logging it to the console?

Comment: I am using Unreal Engine, so `UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), serial.str().c_str());`. Edit: Okay, I just realized about the problem, I am printing it as an array of chars ("%s") so no matter how I format it, it will be interpreted as an array of chars. Thanks @Botje for the clues :)

Comment: You forgot to include that very important bit of context. Because [UE_LOG wants a `TCHAR*` instead of `char*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407427/inlining-the-unrealengine-ue-log-macro-with-c). If you just pass a `char*` it will interpret each two bytes as a composite 16-bit character, which leads to tears. In summary: your way of constructing the hex string was just fine, but your way of printing it was flawed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of the `std::setw()`, `std::setfill()` and `std::hex` manipulators to set the width and fill characters. Also, you need to explicitly cast a `char` variable to an `int` in order to get the numerical representation, otherwise the `<<` operator (on a `char`) will output (or attempt to output) the represented character.

Here's a short example using the `std::cout` stream (though the manipulators work in the same way on a `std::stringstream` object):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    char c = 13;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl; // Shows 0d
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _you need to explicitly cast a char variable to an int_ Yep, thought that might be it :)